# Swf object doesn't seem to work inside a Blogger post

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject, blogger, script-tag

Any ideas why?

On the following link, where it says "So..." there should be an embedded swf.

http://blog.iainlobb.com/2008/10/wrong-door-creating-papervision3d.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="walkmovie"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var so = new SWFObject("http://content.iainlobb.com/walk.swf", "walk", "400", "400", "9", "#336699");
            so.write("walkmovie");
        </script>
```

Your are missing a div to load the swf.

Edit: I saw you had that div placed in your html. I could load you swf into a simple html. You should load the swfobject library before calling the SWFObject.